# android debug error column 'data3' does not exist

Tags: android, debugging

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'data3' does not exist
whats with data3 column??

**LogCat**

> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{fypj.e/fypj.e.e}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   column 'data3' does not exist
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   column 'data3' does not exist
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:99)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:312)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:87)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   fypj.e.e.onCreate(e.java:48)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>
> **03-24 07:05:36.091:**
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2540):     ... 11
>   more

```
package fypj.e;

import android.app.ListActivity; 
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.provider.Contacts.People; 
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone; 
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.widget.*;  

public class e extends ListActivity  {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter;     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ""); 
        values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ""); 
        Uri rawContactUri = 
getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values); 
        long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri); 


        values.clear(); 
        values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId); 
        values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); 
        values.put(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Misha"); 
        values.put(Phone.LABEL, "Mis");
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View Contact");
        getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values); 


        //contentResolver = getContentResolver(); 



        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);         
        startManagingCursor(cursor);          
        String[] column = new String[] {Phone.LABEL};         
        int[] names = new int[] {R.id.contact_name};         
        myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, column, names);         
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);     
    } 
}
```

Comment: It would seem obvious to me that there is a LOT more information needed to answer this question. Why not add some code? Put some effort in.

Comment: I hardly doubt that anyone could answer this question asked like this. Give us more info. What are you trying to do, where the exception is thrown some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which sdk are you using but in 2.2 most of the packets are depricated. However the problem is that the column Phone.Label which has constant value "data3" is not present in the columns return by the cursor.

Comment: i am using 2.2. What do you mean by packet being depreciated??
how do i go bout solving it?

Comment: for instance http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.ContactMethods.html Constacts.People is deprecated e.g is no longer supported and you should avoid using it. Check in the docs which are the supported columns to see which one you could select.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing but guesses possible but maybe you are using "data3" as an argument to some function that does database work, and "data3" does not exist in your database?

Comment: i am not sure about that. How do i check or go bout this problem??